# Gcloud: Deploy local image without pushing to registry

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have a local image that works fine locally. I want to deploy it to my gcloud kubectl. Is there a way I can deploy it without pushing it to container registry. When I do it its throwing:
docker pull access denied repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I have the image locally, so why would I need to pull it from the registry. The only way I have been working is pushing the image to gcr.io.

Just wondering, if there is a workaround

Comment: Are you trying to run it directly on a compute engine instance with Docker or on google kubernetes engine?

Answer (score 0):

Since your cluster is hosted in the cloud (gcloud), it doesn't have any kind of connection with your local machine.

To be able to do so, you'll need to share the/var/run/docker.sock of your local machine with the remote one. Even though, it's really bad idea to share the socket.

That's why, when you're trying to pull an image, if you don't specify any registry host, it will try to pull the image from dockerhub.